# Converting between NEC and HEX values from IR receiver

Tags: esp8266, ir

I jacked one of the IR receivers from my LED strip and hooked it up to my ESP8266 NodeMCU (running Arduino code). I found a great library called [IRremoteESP8266](https://github.com/markszabo/IRremoteESP8266). With this library, I can basically receive and send IR signals. However, the HEX values I get in are different from the NEC values I have to send out.

Here's what I've got:

```
Serial.println((uint32_t) (results.value & 0xFFFFFFFF), HEX);
```

When I compile this and I open the Serial Monitor, I get `D7E84B1B` when I press the button on my remote. I searched for it on Google, and I found a site that shows this:

```
‘real’ decode: FF02FD, hash decode: D7E84B1B
```

So naturally I tried doing:

```
irsend.sendNEC(0x00FF02FD, 32);
```

and it works just fine. The code example for [receiving](https://github.com/markszabo/IRremoteESP8266/blob/master/examples/IRrecvDemo/IRrecvDemo.ino) and [sending](https://github.com/markszabo/IRremoteESP8266/blob/master/examples/IRsendDemo/IRsendDemo.ino) can be found on [the repository](https://github.com/markszabo/IRremoteESP8266).

How do I make a conversion between what I receive and what I send, so I can basically mirror what I do?

EDIT:

According to [the website I got the real NEC value from](https://eletroarduino.wordpress.com/tag/ir-receiver-module/), they simply do:

```
Serial.print(results.value, HEX);
```

However, when I try to do that, I get this error:

> call of overloaded 'println(uint64_t&, int)' is ambiguous

I know they are different projects, but the ESP8266 project I use is based off the IRremote library, which they seem to use.

Comment: There is a comment in the linked receiving code: `// print() & println() can't handle printing long longs. (uint64_t)`  you could just try casting it back to uint32_t - `Serial.print((uint32_t)results.value, HEX);`